# how to get the largest n values in the dictionary but keep the position

Tags: python, dictionary

The original dictionary is :

```
{'gfg': 1, 'best': 6, 'geeks': 3, 'for': 7, 'is': 4}
```

The top `N = 3` value pairs are  `['for', 'best', 'is']` (sorted by value) but I need `['best', 'for', 'is']` (original dictionary order).

Comment: just iterate over the dictionary again and get the original order

Comment: Ah top three scores in the order they appear in the dictionary not in descending order of value. Thank you @Selcuk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries are insertion ordered, but we can't really talk about a position. An acceptable solution could be:

```
>>> d = {'gfg': 1, 'best': 6, 'geeks': 3, 'for': 7, 'is': 4}
>>> cutoff = sorted(d.values())[-3]
>>> [k for k, v in d.items() if v >= cutoff][:3]
['best', 'for', 'is']
```

Comment: @JiříBaum Correct, but that case is undefined in the question anyway. Update: Added a trivial fix to make sure that the length of the resulting list is at most 3.

Comment: Yeah, either may be the requirement; just an additional point for the OP to consider

Comment: I believe that you can then just do something to the effect of `[k for k, v in d.items() if v >= cutoff][:3]` and it will be the same three items from `sorted(d.items(), lambda x:x[1])` since `sorted` is stable\

Comment: Indeed; you still need to think whether those are the ones you should be returning in the case of ties; in many circumstances you may instead want all of them, or some other resolution